# C# Custom user settings class not saving

Tags: c#, settings

I have the following class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot ( ElementName = "TextData", IsNullable = false)]
public class TextData
{
    private System.Drawing.Font fontColor;

    [XmlAttribute ( AttributeName = "Font" )]
    public System.Drawing.Font Font { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute ( AttributeName = "FontColor" )]
    public System.Drawing.Color FontColor { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute ( AttributeName = "Text" )]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public TextData ( )
    {
    } // End of TextData
} // End of TextData
```

And Im attempting to save it with the following code:

```
    // Create our font dialog
    FontDialog fontDialog = new FontDialog ( );
    fontDialog.ShowColor = true;

    // Display the dialog and check for an ok
    if ( DialogResult.OK == fontDialog.ShowDialog ( ) )
    {
        // Save our changes for the font settings
        if ( null == Properties.Settings.Default.MainHeadlineTextData )
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.MainHeadlineTextData = new TextData ( );
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.MainHeadlineTextData.Font = fontDialog.Font;
        Properties.Settings.Default.MainHeadlineTextData.FontColor = fontDialog.Color;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save ( );
    }
```

Everytime I load the the application, the Properties.Settings.Default.MainHeadlineTextData is still null. Saving does not seem to take effect. I read on another post that the class must be public and it is. Any ideas why this would not be working properly?

Comment: When do you load the data? And what does _that_ code look like?

Comment: The settings are loaded automatically via the .Net framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't work because Color and Font are not xml-serializable.
Even more than that, Font does not have parameterless constructor so **Settings.Save()** fails to serialize your object and doesn't save anything.

Unfortunately, by default infrastructure under class **SettingsBase** (from which your **Settings** class is inherited - see auto-generated code in *Settings.Designer.cs* file) doesn't throw exception on serialization error so you can't see the problem.

Remove Font and Color properties from your class and try again.

### Another solution

Another solution is to use binary serialization.
Open *Settings.Designer.cs* file and add attribute [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)] to the property **Settings.MainHeadlineTextData**.

Comment: Thank you. With your help I added [XmlIgnore] to the Font and Color options and used some serialization code from: http://devblog.antongochev.net/2008/06/26/serializedeserialize-a-font-tofrom-xml/ to get it working.

Comment: SettingsSerializeAs.Binary works well but I've found I need to add the attribute again if the designer is used to add a new setting.

Answer (score 2):

To save classes to the application settings config file, the class must either support a TypeConverter or be XMLSerializable.

Your code does not implement a TypeConverter for your custom class, and the Color and Font classes are not XMLSerialiable.

How to implement a type converter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

- Note, that if you do a full recompile the application get a new version internally so it is looking in another folder for the settings - and will of course find none and create a new default one.
- When you save the data, no exceptio is thrown?
- If you insert a breakpoint into the TextData constructor, is it called on application load?